# How do I show/hide a div on field validation with parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

So I guess for context, here is an example from the parsley.js documentation.

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate>
  <div class="first">
    <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" data-parsley-range="[4, 20]" data-parsley-group="block1" />

    <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" data-parsley-range="[4, 20]" data-parsley-group="block1" />
  </div>
  <hr></hr>
  <div class="second">
    <label for="fullname">Fullname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" data-parsley-range="[8, 40]" data-parsley-group="block2" />
  </div>

  <div class="invalid-form-error-message"></div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default validate" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#demo-form').parsley().subscribe('parsley:form:validate', function (formInstance) {

    // if one of these blocks is not failing do not prevent submission
    // we use here group validation with option force (validate even non required fields)
    if (formInstance.isValid('block1', true) || formInstance.isValid('block2', true)) {
      $('.invalid-form-error-message').html('');
      return;
    }
    // else stop form submission
    formInstance.submitEvent.preventDefault();

    // and display a gentle message
    $('.invalid-form-error-message')
      .html("You must correctly fill the fields of at least one of these two blocks!")
      .addClass("filled");
    return;
  });
});
</script>
```

Let's say I have a hidden div called "checkmark".  How would I show this div upon validation of the firstname field?

I should also clarify that I have read the documentation, but still don't understand how to accomplish what I'm trying to do here, so posting a link to the documentation is not really going to be helpful unless you are using it in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Parsley's Events](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events). Since you want to display or hide something based on a *field* validation, you should use `parsley:field:success` and `parsley:field:error`.

Working example ([**with jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/decr9otq/)):

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate>
    <div class="first">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" data-parsley-range="[4, 20]" data-parsley-group="block1" required />
        <div class="hidden" id="checkmark">This message will be shown when the firstname is not valid </div>

        <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" data-parsley-range="[4, 20]" data-parsley-group="block1" />
    </div>
    <hr></hr>
    <div class="second">
        <label for="fullname">Fullname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" data-parsley-range="[8, 40]" data-parsley-group="block2" />
    </div>

    <div class="invalid-form-error-message"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default validate" />
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#demo-form').parsley().subscribe('parsley:form:validate', function (formInstance) {        
        // if one of these blocks is not failing do not prevent submission
        // we use here group validation with option force (validate even non required fields)
        if (formInstance.isValid('block1', true) || formInstance.isValid('block2', true)) {
            $('.invalid-form-error-message').html('');
            return;
        }
        // else stop form submission
        formInstance.submitEvent.preventDefault();

        // and display a gentle message
        $('.invalid-form-error-message')
        .html("You must correctly fill the fields of at least one of these two blocks!")
        .addClass("filled");
        return;
    });

    $.listen('parsley:field:error', function(ParsleyField) {
        if(ParsleyField.$element.attr('name') === 'firstname') {
            $("div#checkmark").addClass('show').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });

    $.listen('parsley:field:success', function(ParsleyField) {
        if(ParsleyField.$element.attr('name') === 'firstname') {
            $("div#checkmark").addClass('hidden').removeClass('show');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's what I did:

1. Added a div with `ìd=checkmark` after the `firstname` field (with a hidden class, since you're using Bootstrap).
2. Added this block of javascript:

   ```
   $.listen('parsley:field:error', function(ParsleyField) {
       if(ParsleyField.$element.attr('name') === 'firstname') {
           $("div#checkmark").addClass('show').removeClass('hidden');
       }
   });

   $.listen('parsley:field:success', function(ParsleyField) {
       if(ParsleyField.$element.attr('name') === 'firstname') {
           $("div#checkmark").addClass('hidden').removeClass('show');
       }
   });
   ```

   This code will listen to the validation of every input validated by Parsley. This means that when the field `lastname` fails, the code inside `$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(ParsleyField) {` will be executed. This is why I used an `if` to check if the attr name is `firstname`.

   Then you show or hide the div based on the validation result.
3. Added `required` to the field, so the message is displayed when you click on the button.